# PLSQL move data from csv list stored in varchar2 to a collection of integers

Tags: sql, oracle, collections, plsql

Oracle Express 11G R2: 
In PLSQL I have a varchar2 containing a CSV list of values like this:

```
vList:='1212,3232,3232,4343,54545,65654,65665,65654,788787'
```

I would like to move these into a collection, so i create a new type:

```
CREATE TYPE INTEGER_TT AS TABLE OF INTEGER;
```

then declare my variable:

```
my_list INTEGER_TT;
```

What is the quickest (in terms of processor time, not implementation time) way to populate "my_list" with the values from the varchar2 containing the CSV?

This is my current code, the query on its own runs in about 0.01s, with the "bulk collect into" added it takes around 6s with a list of about 500 values.

```
select regexp_substr( vList,'[^,]+', 1, level) intID 
bulk collect into my_list
from dual connect by regexp_substr(vList, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null;
```

Any better options than my code above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performance is going to vary depending on platform, configuration etc. so a definitive answer is going to be difficult. 0.1s for the regex seems a lot, and increasing to 6s to populate a collection seems excessive.

Since your string only consists of numbers you can try a trick with XMLTable:

```
select to_number(column_value)
bulk collect into my_list
from xmltable(vList);
```

This passes your CSV list as [an XQuery expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb_xquery.htm#ADXDB5091), and it's interpreted as an XQuery sequence. This only works for numbers though, you can't use this method for strings.

Sample timings to compare the methods with the same 500-element list, generated with random integers:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  my_list INTEGER_TT;
  vList varchar2(32767);
  vTime pls_integer;
begin
  -- create list of 500 random integers
  vTime := dbms_utility.get_time;
  select listagg(trunc(dbms_random.value(1, 10000)), ',')
    within group (order by null)
  into vList
  from dual
  connect by level <= 500;
  dbms_output.put_line('Creating list took ' || (dbms_utility.get_time - vTime));

  -- original regex approach
  vTime := dbms_utility.get_time;
  select regexp_substr( vList,'[^,]+', 1, level) intID 
  bulk collect into my_list
  from dual connect by regexp_substr(vList, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null;
  dbms_output.put_line('Regex took ' || (dbms_utility.get_time - vTime));

  -- XMLTable approach
  vTime := dbms_utility.get_time;
  select to_number(column_value)
  bulk collect into my_list
  from xmltable(vList);
  dbms_output.put_line('XMLTable took ' || (dbms_utility.get_time - vTime));
end;
/
```

gets the following times, in hundredths of a second:

```
Creating list took 2
Regex took 188
XMLTable took 3
```

You may since different results, or a different magnitude of difference...

---

If you're doing this to use the collection as a data source in a SQL query - which is possible as it's a schema-level collection type - you may be able to skip that step. If you were using `table(my_list)`, you can refer to `xmltable(vList)` directly instead. You can potentially avoid PL/SQL altogether, depending on exactly what you're doing; though you could have done that anyway with a CTE.

Comment: Great solution, my results from your query:  Creating list took 89
Regex took 1062
XMLTable took 6

Comment: Hi @Alex, just a note, it seems the maximum size that vList could be is 4000, over this amount the "from xmltable(vList) gives an error: "ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested"  I can't see any way around this.

Comment: @ASims - this is using XMLTable in a SQL context, where string size is limited to 4000 (until 12c anyway). You'd need to make `vList` a CLOB to go above that length. (Verified that with a CLOB containing 1000 numbers, which was 4874 long).